# Ошибка установки symfony/web-server-bundle

Tags: symfony3

Разварачиваю проект на Windows почти закончил, но нужно было установить symfony/web-server-bundle, устанавливаю командой

```
composer require symfony/web-server-bundle --dev
```

Получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

upgrade 1:

проблема с версиями решена командой

```
 composer require symfony/web-server-bundle:"~3.0"--dev
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если ввести команду

```
php bin/console
```

server команд там нет

поэтому локальный сервер так и не могу запустить, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: От сюда: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25314 "That's how Composer behaves. If you omit the version, it will pick the highest stable version which is 4.0. So you have to be explicit here." В composer.json укажи версию которую хочешь установить. Например ```"symfony/web-server-bundle": "^3.4"```. Или просто ```composer require server:3.4```

Comment: @user3841429 обновил информацию сверху, может подскажите что?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cоздаем файл в корне проекта .env с содержимым

```
APP_ENV=dev
```

и затем выполняем

bin/console server:run